# I can not log in to my site by facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

[image: OAuth authenticate error]

I used to log in (about 1 month ago). But now a new user of my site gets this error when he is trying to log in. If user logged in once (facebook OAuth) 2 month ago, then he can log in successfully. However new users cannot log in. What is  the reason? What I have to do?

Comment: what does the error message say in english?

Comment: Application is not configured: The developers of this application have not configured the application to log on to Facebook.

Comment: check your app settings and maybe post them as screenshot too

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21533228/ac-1.PNG

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21533228/ac-2.PNG

Comment: I can’t find any option to log in using Facebook on http://asiacrochet.com/

Comment: I turned off, sorry. Now you can try it.

Comment: Try putting your domain into the App Domain settings field. If that doesn’t help, double-check your app id (since you blanked it in the screenshot, I can’t tell whether it matches the one you are using on your site).